# How to delete record in MongoDB using Spring Data

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I want to delete an record based on Id in Spring. 
but in database id value is object
EX:-

```
id: Object(34562341112313)
```

How to delete this record in Spring?

Comment: What did you find when you googled?

Answer (score 2):

You do like this:

```
public void deleteRecord() {
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("id").is(34562341112313));
    mongoOperation.remove(searchQuery, Your_entity_class.class);
    logger.info("Delete success");
}
```

This is my realistic example:

```
/**
 * Delete by condition(s).
 */
public void deleteJob() {
    MongoOperations mongoOperation = (MongoOperations) ctx.getBean("mongoTemplate");
    Query searchQuery = new Query(Criteria.where("company").is("DCV"));
    mongoOperation.remove(searchQuery, Job.class);
    logger.info("Đã xóa các công việc đăng bởi DCV.");
}
```

Source: https://github.com/SmartJobVN/MongoDB_SpringDataMongo/blob/master/src/main/java/vn/smartJob/jobs/MongoSpringJavaConfigApplication.java#L132

Reference: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/mongodb/docs/current/reference/html/

Comment: Thanks dovy. I hope it will help full.

Comment: Any way to know if delete was successfull or failed? Is there any way to get acknowledgement?

Comment: @HIRATHAKUR The `remove` method returns a `DeleteResult`, which has a method to get the count of deleted records.

Answer (score 1):

```
  @Query(value = "{'_id' : ?0}", delete = true)
  void deleteById(String id);
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, it would be better to include some context, explaining how it works and when to use it. Code-only answers are not useful in the long run.

Answer (score 0):

You should delete it like this:

```
@Repository
public class AppDaoClass{
    @Autowired
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;
    @Override
    public void deleteSomething(String somethingId) {
        mongoTemplate.remove(Query.query(Criteria.where("somethingId").is(somethingId)), Ticket.class);
    }
}
```

*The first "somethingId" is the name you gave it in your model, and the second somethingId is for the Parametar you are giving in you method*.

And your Domain Model:

```
@Document
public class Model {

    @Id
    private String somethingId;
    private String someName;
    private String someOtherName;
}
```

Be sure to user proper annotations for your classes **@Document** and **@Repository**. And add an **@Id** annotation to your ID field.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

**This is the way you can delete records in spring data mongoDB using MongoTemplate**

```
WriteResult writeResult=mongoTemplate.remove(query,"collection_name");
```

**OR**

```
 WriteResult writeResult=mongoTemplate.remove(query,EntityClassName.class);
```

**You can also use repository Pattern**

```
@Document(collection = "user")
public class User {

@Id
private String id;
private String username;

public String getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(String id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}
}

@Repository
public interface UserRepository extend MongoRepository<User, String>{
     public void delete(String id);
     public void delete(User user);
     public void deleteByUsername(String username);
}
```

you can use these method anywhere to delete records also u can write your custom methods